# VirtualBox RawDisk error : VERR ACCESS DENIED

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, access-denied, raw-disk

I'd like to boot VirtualBox to the external hard drive I have that runs Windows 8 To Go, as the computer running virtual box is one that I can't boot to the drive during certain hours, but I'd still like to be able to interact with the OS on that drive.

I found a guide for creating a raw VM DK disk file for my external drive, and ran the commands for it in an administrator command prompt, which was listed as a requirement in the article I was reading.

At first, I'd boot to the drive with my VirtualBox machine, and it would ask me to enter the BitLocker encryption password.

I'd enter it, and before the spinning circles of the Windows loading logo would make a complete rotation, VBox would give me an error popup saying "Error: VERR_ACCESS DENIED".

I researched the issue a bit online and found that some users had resolved this issue by turning on 'Use host I/O cache' on the VirtualBox Storage controller.

I tried this, and the machine did indeed make it farther and stopped displaying an error message, only now it stays on the windows loading screen indefinitely, or may even restart itself.

I checked the log file and am seeing several non-displayed error messages of 'VERR_ACCESS DENIED".

Running virtual box itself as an administrator has had no effect.

Has anyone else tried this successfully? Does anyone have any tips? 
I'd appreciate productive suggestions instead of criticism against 'why' I'm doing something.

Thank you!